# Click a div (or something else) and get a datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Ok, so I have the following html.

```
<div class="holder">                                                         
  <span class="mini-arrow"></span>
  <div class="date">
    <p>11</p>
    <p><span>Apr<br />2012</span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="hour">                                                                                         
    <p>3:20</p>                                                                               
    <p><span>pm</span></p>                                                                  
  </div>                                                                                                     
  <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>                                                                               
</div>​
```

What I would like to do is this.

```
$('.date').datepicker()
```

I can't seem to find any documentation to make a jquery-ui-datepicker work on a div like that.

If you know how to do this, or know another (easily styleable) datepicker that does, it would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do this is using the `showOn` option for the `datepicker` widget. Here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q2uJD/1/).

**HTML**

```
<input class="date hidden" />​
```

**JS**

```
$('.date').datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImageOnly: false,
    buttonText : "Select Date"
});​
```

**CSS**

```
​.hidden {
    display:none;
}​
```

Using the HTML you provided this is how it could be applied: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/q2uJD/10/).

Comment: yep, this is how I would do it

Comment: @mwoods79 you can set the model/div's properties using a function which you call onSelect of the datepicker

Comment: @mwoods79 Please see the example added at the end of the answer to make it work with a div.

Comment: @juan.facorro can you give me a link?

Comment: @mwoods79 There's a link in the word "example" above that links [here](http://jsfiddle.net/q2uJD/10/).

Comment: Oh, you changed it, sorry, didn't realize.  Thanks so much.